# XHTML DOM - How to split a tag on IE?

Tags: dom, xhtml, tags, split

Let's assume I have a part of an html document containing the following code (basic structure) :

```
<p>
  <span class="1">This is my first content</span>
  <span class="2">This is my second content</span>
</p>
```

I'd like to allow the user to select a part of the text and apply a new class to it.
Let's say the user selects "is my first" in the first span, and applies class "3".
I'd like to have the following result :

```
<p>
  <span class="1">This </span>
  <span class="3">is my first</span>
  <span class="1"> content</span>
  <span class="2">This is my second content</span>
</p>
```

I've managed to do this on Firefox by using the execCommand "InsertHTML", but I can't find a way to do this in IE (before IE9)
The only result I have is a nested span element, like below :

```
<p>
  <span class="1">This <span class="3">is my first</span> content</span>
  <span class="2">This is my second content</span>
</p>
```

Do you have any idea of how I could achieve this ?
Any help would be much appreciated !
By the way, if this looks too simple to you, how would you handle the case of a user selecting a portion of text that spans over 2 or more spans ? over 2 or more ps ?

Answer (score 0):

you can get the selected segment using selection range. I would recommend using [rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/DocumentationHome), which is a cross browser range module.

Here's some "untested" code using jQuery and Rangy to hopefully point you in the right direction, for your first case:

```
var splitTag=function(class){
    var sel = rangy.getSelection();

    // this is your selection, in your example "is my first"
    var r0 = sel.getRangeAt(0);

    // create a new range       
    var r1 = rangy.createRange();
    // this would be your <p>
    var p = r0.endContainer.parentNode;

    // set the new range to start at the end of your phrase and to end at <p>
    r1.setStart(r0.endContainer, r0.endOffset);
    r1.setEnd(p, p.length-1);

    // extract the content of your first selection "is my first"
    var r0Txt=r0.toHtml();

    // make it into an span, with class set to "class argument" which would be 3 
    var newContent=$("<span/>").html(r0Txt).attr("class", class);

    r0.deleteContents();

    // insert the new node before r1
    r1.insertNode(newContent[0]);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
}
```

this should get you the result for your first situation. for selections across multiple paragraphs, here's a modification of the code:

```
var splitTag=function(class){
    var sel = rangy.getSelection();

    var r0 = sel.getRangeAt(0);

    var r1 = rangy.createRange();
    var p = r0.endContainer.parentNode;

    r1.setStart(r0.endContainer, r0.endOffset);
    r1.setEnd(p, p.length-1);

    var r0Txt=r0.toHtml();

    if(!r0.startContainer===r0.endContainer){
        // the selection spans multiple dom's

        // set the class of all spans in the highlight to 3
        var newContent=$(r0Txt).find("span").attr("class",class);
    }else{
        var newContent=$("<span/>").html(r0Txt).attr("class", class);
    }

    r0.deleteContents();
    r1.insertNode(newContent[0]);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
}
```